# How to get several New Tabs opened with opening Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-tabs

Wonder how to get several New Tabs opened upon opening Microsoft Edge, URL Tabs opening definition is clear and known.

The scenario is to get opened e.g. totally 20 tabs, in a certain order, some with URLs' and most without as New Tabs. Let's say, first on the left Home Page URL, then 2 New Tabs, then another URL, then 4 New Tabs etc.

Edit: As a clarification, the requested e.g. totally 20 tabs should be got opened automatically the same second upon Edge is opened and popping-up on the display, so, they and their exact order on the Edge window should be got defined ready somewhere. I didn't find any possibility in Settings to get the New Tabs defined, as where the URL Tabs.

Comment: You should clarify your question, how open a website in a new Edge tab, is identical to how you do it in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You should edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, an exact answer, already applied, got from EE Carol Chisholm -> "Put about:tabs as the URL where you want the New Tab to appear."

Comment: @DanielB OK, thanks for your hint, didn't yet note to do it but now. But, probably not getting any points for myself ...

Comment: Questions without an accepted answer get pushed to the front page periodically. That's why accepting an answer is important.

Comment: @DanielB OK, and now even got 10 + 5 points, great! Thanks!